# Como saber o atual estado do formulário?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, vb.net, formulário, visual-basic-6

Sou iniciante na área, não consegui achar minha pergunta em outro lugar.

Há algum código, que mostre o estado do form?

Por exemplo: se ele está no foco, se ele está minimizado ou maximizado?

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter ou alterar o estado de um formulário, use [`Form.WindowState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```vb-net
MessageBox.Show(WindowState.ToString()) ' Normal, Maximizado ou Minimizado '
```

Ou se precisar executar uma ação em determinado estado, você pode fazer:

```vb-net
If WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
   ' O formulário está maximizado '
ElseIf WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
   ' O formulário está minimizado '
ElseIf WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
   ' O formulário está normal '
Else
   ' Estado desconhecido '
End If
```

Para saber se um controle está em foco, use [`Control.Focused`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused(v=vs.110).aspx).

```vb-net
If Me.Focused Then
    ' Este formulário está em foco '
Else
    ' Não está em foco '
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Você teria que colocar dois eventos no seu form para anotar o estado dele em uma variável. Por exemplo:

```
Private formAtivo As Boolean

Private Sub meuForm_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
  formAtivo = True
End Sub

Private Sub meuForm_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
  formAtivo = False
End Sub
```

Para saber se o form está ativo, basta ler `formAtivo`. [Tirei a resposta daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093271/how-to-get-a-value-for-form-active-state-in-vb-net).

`formAtivo` não precisa ser `Private`.